# Minecraft 1.14.2 functions not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a function in Minecraft 1.14.2, and it just doesn't work. I tried everything and looked for answers everywhere, but it still doesn't work. I did the following:

- created a `.mcfunction` file in `\<myWorldName>\datapacks\<dataPackName>\data\<nameSpace>\functions`;
- saved it in UTF-8  without BOM (using Notepad++), and later tried ANSI;
- did `/reload` and then `/function <nameSpace>:<functionName>`. It always just writes `"Unknown function <functionName>"`. It didn't work a single time.

My function file is very simple, I just try to test it with something like:

`say 123`

I really don't know what to do next, please, can you help me?

Comment: Check that your function's name doesn't have any reserved characters. Try making that example function be named `example.mcfunction`, because I'm pretty sure capital letters and certain punctuations are off limits.

Comment: Name of my function was test.mcfunction so it wasn't because of punctuation or capital letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need "`pack.mcmeta`" in your `<datapackName>` folder. The wiki tells you what that can all contain, but the simplest case is just:

```
{"pack":{"pack_format":3,"description":""}}
```

Comment: I had that file there but it was slightly different. Your version made it work. Thank you very much!